# Create a simple countdown timer Python

Tags: python

Could someone give me a tip? I am attempting to create a countdown timer that will reset based on the episodes...

For example I was hoping this code below would countdown from 10 - 0, 15 times (`total_episodes`) but it only counts down once... Any tips greatly appreciated..

```
import time

total_episodes = 15 
n=10

for episode in range(total_episodes):

    for i in range(n):
        time.sleep(1)
        n -= 1
        print("countdown episode timer",n)
```

I need the `time.sleep` as my real scenario I am trying to create something that will countdown 10 minutes for 15 times/episodes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're forgetting to reset your `n`.

```
for episode in range(total_episodes):

    n = 10   #  do this

    for i in range(n):
        time.sleep(1)
        n -= 1
        print("countdown episode timer", n)
```

Without resetting your `n`, the nested `for`-loop will evaluate `i in range(0)` which is just an empty range.

**OR** you could even do without the `n`.

```
for episode in range(total_episodes):

    for i in range(10, 0, -1):
        time.sleep(1)
        print("countdown episode timer", i)
```